# Questions about the ReactiveController pattern promoted and used by Lit

Tags: typescript, web-component, lit

Please find below three different ways of implementing some `ReactiveController` with `Lit`.
A typical `ReactiveController` implementation with `Lit` looks like `Pattern 1`.
Please be aware that in `Pattern 2` and `Pattern 3` there's no `implements ReactiveController` as all methods of interface `ReactiveController` are optional by design.
`Pattern 3` uses a factory function to create objects of type `typeof SomeController`. This has for example the advantage that some day in future, depending on the arguments
different subtypes of SomeController may be returned, which is not possible with `Pattern 1` and `Pattern 2`.

Questions:

1. Are `Pattern 2` and `Pattern 3` in some way kinda violating `Lit`'s ReactiveController model/idea?
2. In `Pattern 1`: Are there real-world use cases where instances of `SomeController` will be passed to some `addController` method a second time?
   If no, what do I really need those public methods `hostConnected` and `hostDisconnected` for and why not just always use `Pattern 2` or `Pattern 3` instead (except for "matter of taste" and maybe code readability)?

```js
// Pattern 1

export class SomeController implements ReactiveController {
  ....

  constructor(host: ReactiveControllerHost, ...) {
    ...
    host.addController(this);
    ...
  }
  
  hostConnected() {
    ...
  }

  hostDisconnected() {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

The exact same controller can be implemented in this way:

```js
// Pattern 2

export class SomeController {
  ...

  constructor(host: ReactiveControllerHost, ....) {
    ....
    host.addController({
      hostConnected() {
        ...
      },

      hostDisconnected() {
        ...
      }
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

Also, using a factory function is possible:

```js
// Pattern 3

export function getSomeController(...): typeof SomeController {
  return new SomeController(...);
}

// class SomeController class is local, will not be exported
class SomeController {
  ....

  constructor(host: ReactiveControllerHost, ....) {
    ...    
    host.addController({
      hostConnected() {
        ....
      },

      hostDisconnected() {
        ....
      }
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Not many Lit users here on StackOverflow. For detailed Lit questions, the better place to ask is Lit & Friends: https://lit.dev/docs/resources/community/

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it's due to the fact that the controllers implemented with pattern 2 and pattern 3 cannot be removed later by using `host.removeController(...)`.
So this is against the basic idea of addable and removable reactive controllers.